# How to apply a function in a dataframe spliting the content delimeted by dot in a phrase

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to get the `len` of phrase in a sentence But i need to get the len of every block delimited by `'.'`  For example:

```
text = 'We are happy.We are happy'

len(text) should return [13,13]
```

The phrases can have several sentences, like several dot's: " i am happy. You are happy. The are happy.' and so on

Sometimes there's a blank space between the dot `.` and next letter, for example:

`'we are happy. we are happy'` then this would return [13,14]  but I want to avoid this, I mean, I want to remove any **blank_space**.

This text is in pandas dataframe, so I need to apply to every row:

```
          text
'We are happy.We are happy.'
```

then apply the function to every row:

```
df['output'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x:  function_len(x))
```

to get as result:

```
          text                    output
'We are happy.We are happy.'      [13,13]
```

I am using `len(text.split('.'))` but it returns 3.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
text = 'We are happy. We are happy.'
new_text = text.replace(". ", ".")
new_text = new_text.split('.')
for i in range(len(new_text)-1):
    print(len(new_text[i]))
```

Using pandas apply:

```
import pandas as pd

sentences = [1,2]
text = ["We are happy. We are happy", "We are sad. We are sad."]
        

df = pd.DataFrame([sentences, text]).T
df.columns = ["Number", "Sentences"]

def text_len(text):
    new_text = text.replace(". ", ".")
    new_text = new_text.split('.')
    lengths = []
    for i in range(len(new_text)-1):
        lengths.append(len(new_text[i]))
    return(lengths)
df.Sentences.apply(lambda x: text_len(x))
```

Comment: Is this not working for you?